# SQL Server 2008 - Login failed for user 'user1' The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows XP.

In installation process I selected 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode'

When I click right button of the mouse in SQL Server Management Studio on Server -> Security tab 'SQL server and Windows Authentication Mode' is selected.

But when I click on my Database -> Properties - View connection properties Authentication Method is set on Windows Authentication.

To my database was added one `user1` with password `user1`.

But I can't log in to my database from C# (Visual Studio 2008) because error occurs:

> Login failed for user 'user1'  The
>   user is not associated with a trusted
>   SQL Server connection

What isn't right ?

---

When I get:

```
string connectionStr = @"Data Source=rmzcmp\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ResourcesTmp;Integrated Security=True";
```

I have following error:

{"Cannot open database \"ResourcesTmp\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'RMZCMP\rm'."}

rm is my original user name on which I log in to my computer.
When I get rm I have error:

```
{"Login failed for user 'rm'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection."}
```

again.

Regards

Comment: Set integrated Security to false then add a user and password to your connection string in your case User Id=user1;
Password=user1;

Comment: "Data Source=rmzcmp\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ResourcesTmp;Integrated Security=False;User Id=user1; Password=user1;";

Answer (score 1):

You say a user was created in your database - did you also create a **login** to your server?

In SQL Server 2005 and up, security is a two-step process:

- you first must define a **login** that enables a user to even log in to that SQL Server
- based on that login, you can define **user** in your individual databases

Also: you're not showing us your connection string, so we can only guess what settings you're using. From the error message, I'm almost guessing you're using `Integrated Security` in your connection string - but from your other points in the question, it seems you've created a specific user (and possibly a login for that user) - so you don't want to use integrated (Windows) security...

Most likely, your connection string is invalid - or you're missing a login - or both. You need to give us a bit more information for us to be able to really help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your Connection string based on :

[Connection string.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Make sure that your installation of SQL Server is successful.

Ex:

1. If you can create a SQL Server authentication login
2. You can login using username/password in SQL Server authentication. Use a connection string like:

   ```
   Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=user;Password=sa
   ```

But

1. If you can login using only windows authentication there is something wrong in your installation. Use connection string:

   ```
   Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True
   ```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests your application is set to log in with "trusted" (i.e. Windows) credentials and that the Windows account that the program is running as doesn't have a login on the server.  Based on the way that you phrased the adding of a user, my guess is that it's a SQL login and you should change your connection string to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I created user on my machine (where ms sql is installed)
User name is user1 and password too.
I can log on to Ms sql server on this user (user1)
My connection string is:

```
string connectionStr = @"Data Source = rmzcmp\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog = ResourcesTmp; User Id = user1; Password = user1;";
```

I user MS SQL Server 2008

rmzcmp is my computer name.
In ResourcesTmp (my database) ->Security ->Users I have: dbo, guest, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, sys, user1, user2
I don't have sa user.
User1 has following permissions:
Schemas owned by this user:
db_accessadmin
db_datareader
db_datawriter
Database role membership
db_accessadmin
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_owner

Server properties -> Permissions ->Explicit tab:
Connect SQL : Grantor sa, Grant true.
User1 all checkboxes has false

Security tab -> Server authentication : SQL Serve and Windows Authentication mode is selected as I mentioned in earlier post

Regards

Comment: You shouldn't add "dummy answers" to provide more information - instead, please **update your original question** by editing it!

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if the user tries to log in with credentials that cannot be validated. This problem can occur in the following scenarios:

Scenario 1: The login may be a SQL Server login but the server only accepts Windows Authentication.

Scenario 2: You are trying to connect by using SQL Server Authentication but the login used does not exist on SQL Server.

Scenario 3: The login may use Windows Authentication but the login is an unrecognized Windows principal. An unrecognized Windows principal means that Windows can't verify the login. This might be because the Windows login is from an untrusted domain.

To resolve this problem, follow the steps that apply to your scenario.
Scenario 1: Configure SQL Server in Mixed Authentication Mode.

SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2005
Open SQL Server Management Studio. To do this, click Start, click All Programs, click Microsoft SQL Server 200x (where x is the version of SQL), and then click SQL Server Management Studio.
Right-click the server, and then click Properties. See image. 
On the Security page, under Server authentication, click the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode option button, and then click OK. See image. 
In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to restart SQL Server.

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332